# Is there a difference between dereferencing directly and through subscripts?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char, dereference

I'm trying to overload a + operator on a custom string class but when I'm using subscripts instead of directly dereferencing the pointers I get leaks at the end when I hit pause on my main function.

I've run the debugger multiple times but the result is the same, using the uncommented code above gives me a leak and the commented one works.

```
MyString MyString::operator+(const MyString& s) {
MyString temp;
temp.sz = (sz + s.sz);
temp.ptr = new char[sz+1];
temp.ptr[temp.sz] = '\0';
for(int i = 0; i < sz; i++){
    temp.ptr[i] = ptr[i];
}
for (int i = sz; i < temp.sz; i++) {
    temp.ptr[i] = s.ptr[i-sz];
}
return temp;

/*MyString temp;
int size = strlen(ptr) + strlen(s.ptr);
temp.ptr = new char[size + 1];
*(temp.ptr + size) = '\0';
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(ptr); i++)
    *(temp.ptr + i) = *(ptr + i);
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s.ptr); i++)
    *(temp.ptr + i + strlen(ptr)) = *(s.ptr + i);
return temp;*/
```

}

Using the uncommented code above gives me a leak and the commented one works without any leak.

Comment: The two versions are not logically equivalent. One uses `strlen`, other uses other variables to compute memory allocation size. It is likely that there are other bugs in code that's not shown, that triggers memory leaks. In any case, without a [mcve] it is not possible to tell you anything, except that the shown code (both versions) exhibits many error-prone programming practices that can easily lead to memory leaks, especially if the rest of the class is not Rule Of 3-compliant.

Comment: There is other difference: `temp.sz` vs `int size`

Comment: `temp.ptr = new char[sz+1];` is going to cause problems.

Comment: `temp.ptr[temp.sz] = '\0'` gives undefined behaviour if `s.sz` and `sz` are both positive (presumably both are guaranteed to be non-negative).   Look at the two preceding statements that assign `temp.sz` and `temp.ptr` to see why.   Memory leaks are one possible side effect of undefined behaviour (depending, of course, on how you detect a memory leak).

Comment: `temp.ptr = new char[sz+1];`  --> `temp.ptr = new char[temp.sz+1];`